# What does "readelf: Warning: Corrupt offset in range entry N" mean?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, elf, readelf

I am running `readelf -w` on my (C++) executable to examine some debug sections and it prints the following warnings a couple of times:

```
$ readelf -w a.out
...
readelf: Warning: Corrupt offset (0x00000028) in range entry 1
readelf: Warning: Corrupt offset (0x00000044) in range entry 2
readelf: Warning: Corrupt offset (0x00000054) in range entry 3
...
```

I have no clue what this means and neither the manpage nor Google could help.
Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from `dwarf.c` [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=binutils/dwarf.c;h=71d8bc9ed5c86cce851a2726ae672c63215b8135;hb=HEAD#l8245):

```
  for (i = 0; i < num_range_list; i++)
...
      if (offset > (size_t) (finish - section_begin))
        {
          warn (_("Corrupt offset (%#" PRIx64 ") in range entry %u\n"),
                offset, i);
          continue;
        }
```

What this means is hard to say without seeing output from `readelf --all`. It could be that your compiler is producing bad debug info, but it could also be a bug in `readelf`, possibly [this one](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28012).

You could try using `eu-readelf` from the [elfutils](https://sourceware.org/elfutils/) package, which appears to be better maintained.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What particular information do you expect to be useful from `readelf --all`?

Answer (score 1):

This could also mean that the binary was compiled with `-ffunction-sections` and then linked with `ld --gc-sections` which leaves dropped sections untouched with "corrupted ranges".

See https://maskray.me/blog/2021-02-28-linker-garbage-collection